# cocos2d 2.1 and HKTMXLayer opacity problems

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a game with coco2d 2.1 and I currently started using the HKTMXTiledMap extension.

Overall, the extension is great, anyone who is making a game with tiled maps (especially big ones) should check it out. But I need to be able to change the opacity of the layers during the course of my levels.

I have tried changing the shader and drawing methods, but there must be something I'm missing.

I changed line 97 of HKTMXLayer.m to: `self.shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTextureColor];`, but then the layer is shown all black.

Anyone got any tips for me? Thanks!

Comment: do you create your own draw method ? if yes, make certain you initialize the shader's attibutes properly at the top of your draw.

Comment: anyone who is making a game with tiled maps should **really** be checking out KoboldTouch: http://www.koboldtouch.com/x/cYBq  Couldn't resist. :)
Oh and of course changing layer opacity definitely works in KoboldTouch.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I am trying to alter the HKTMXLayer class from [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/develop-v2/Extensions/HKTMXTiledMap).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I'll check that out! Only changing the framework after a year developing with cocos2d wouldn't be practical. hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was posted [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17945/page/10?replies=273#post-461139).

Along with changing the shader to `kCCShader_PositionTextureColor`, the color attribute needed to be passed when drawing the layer.

`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

```
glVertexAttrib4f(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, color_.r/255., color_.g/255., color_.b/255., opacity_/255.);
```

glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

Answer (score 0):

not certain of your overall context, but the draw method of the same class (line 465) is only seting the 'position' attribute : which is normal considering the class derives from 'CCNode'.

The shader you are setting (normally for a sprite) needs a vertices attribute, as well as a colors attrib. See the code in CCSprite (draw) for an example. Maybe there is another way to meet your need (the 'why' you are changing the shader for a Node derivative class to a shader normally used for CCSprite/textures).